# Run Bibtex on aux files in subfolders, multiple OS

Tags: bibtex, compiling, texmaker, include, auxiliary-files

I have a complete framework for my PhD thesis based on classicthesis/arsclassica. Single chapters are located in Subfolders like this.

- main.tex
- Chapters/project1/project1.tex
- Chapters/project2/project2.tex
- ...

I am using `chapterbib` to have a references section after each chapter. The chapter files are included in the main document via `\include`, so that I get separate `.aux` files in each subfolder. I need to run bibtex on the `.aux` files in the subfolders so that the `.bbl` files necessary for the chapter references are created.

All my machines both at work and at home are running Linux, I am using Vim as an editor and have written a simple shell script to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash
pdflatex main.tex
for auxfile in $(find * -name "*.aux"); do bibtex $auxfile; done
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

Now, I have given the template to a friend, she is using both Windows and OS X. Her editor is Texmaker. The given compile profiles all do not work for this, since they do not run `bibtex` on the other files. Manually opening the subchapters and executing `bibtex` works on my machine, oddly enough even this was not really working for her either, but I need to check it again. Anyways, an automatic routine would be preferred.

If I add something like this

```
for auxfile in $(find * -name "*.aux"); do bibtex $auxfile; done
```

as a user specified command in Texmaker on the Mac, I am getting the Message `"Error: Could not start the command"`, even though it works when I execute it from the command line.

So, I am looking for a solution (or two) to add a profile that does the usual compilation routine plus also runs bibtex on the .aux files of the \included chapters. Needs to work in OS X and in Windows, so probably the solutions are going to be distinct. If necessary, I can upload a minimal working example which I have prepared.

Comment: There is no "profile" in Texmaker but "user commands". And these commands are not bash commands (bash is not supported on windows - an "user command" is only a chain of executable commands on the system). But you can create a bash script on MacOsx and a .bat script on windows and then launch the script with an "user command" in Texmaker.

Comment: Indeed, what I meant where the user commands. I am aware that bash does not work on Windows, but it should on MacOsx. But for some reason, this doesn't work. Even if I create a bash script like the one above and create a Texmaker user command to execute it, it doesn't work. In addition, I have no idea how to create a similar script that would work on windows. The "chain of executable commands" is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: No idea about Windows and essentially none about Macs, but are you sure your commands on the Mac are getting executed in the right `bash` 'environment' (think: `env`).  Also why you're at it, why not make a real Makefile or (let your friend) use something like [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/)?

Comment: 1) The script must be really executable (it can't be launched by "sh myscript.sh" which is a bash command to launch a bash script) and the script must be really reachable by Texmaker (in the path, or with the full path to the script, or by using a parameter : in Texmaker, the ! parameter will be replaced by the current directory).
2) As said Jon : using a tool like latexmk will be more cross-platform compliant.

Comment: Ok, I was using the `sh myscript.sh` route. will try to make the script executable and see if it works, I'll try to tinker a bit with it next time I get access to a Mac. Still clueless about scripting in Windows, but I guess it should work similar. Odd that there is no canned solution for this, can't be that rare a situation that people need multiple chapter bibliographies.

Comment: @ilprincipe At least one 'canned' solution has been mentioned here, hasn't it?

Comment: You mean `latexmk`? I am not familiar with it yet but I'll look into it.